# Swap() in STL algorithm C++

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Why `swap()` in STL algorithm don't take address of a variable and passing variable work just fine but in C++ call by value don't change actual value but call by address changes actual parameter?

Comment: Please, research references... They are a fundamental feature of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::swap` is actually a template function. So if you look at the way `std::swap` is being called:

```
template< class T >
void swap( T& a, T& b ) noexcept
```

It means despite that you seem to be passing the parameter's by value, the template would actually deduce the types to the corresponding address of the parameter.

For instance, if you have a code like:

```
int a1 = 1;
int a2 = 2;
std::swap(a1, a2);
```

When you run `std::swap(a1, a2)`, the type of `a1` and `a2` would be passed to the template, which make `T` as `int`.

Then it replace the `T` in the function as `int` and generate a function like:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
...
}
```

So the `std::swap` is actually taking the address of those value, but you just don't need to write them out when you call the function.

Comment: Talk of addresses seems prone to create confusion with pointers. What are passed/received are **references**. Sure, using those in practice means taking the address, but that's just an implementation detail. Anyway, I'm not sure OP not having read enough about the language to know what references are justifies a question or answer.